# Patient monitoring (raw data) in Fhir

Tags: c#, database, hl7-fhir

What is the best way to save raw data in fhir?
For example, I want to save the heart rate data of a patient which is obtained by monitoring the patient for 10 hours a day, every day of the week.

Do I have to create for each measurement from an `observation` or is there any more convenient method to store the data ?

So far I have tried to save the data through Observation:

```
Observation observation = new Observation
{
    Status = ObservationStatus.Final,
    Code = new CodeableConcept($"http://loinc.org", "12345-6"),
    Subject = new ResourceReference($"Patient/{measurementData.PatientId}"),
    Value = new FhirString(measurementData.Value), // Example value and unit
    Issued = DateTime.Now
};
```

Comment: "*What is the best way*" - This will only lead to opinionated answers, which makes your question off-topic on SO. Please have a look at [ask]. What have you tried? What is not working? Where are you stuck

Comment: @DarkBee then what is the solution ?

Comment: Be more specific why your current approach is not working

Comment: @DarkBee If you can't help, it's better not to comment =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truly 'raw' data would be stored using Binary - which can store anything with a mime type.  However, Binary is opaque from a FHIR search perspective.  If you want 'concise' representation of a large volume of data in a single Observation, you can also look at the SampledData data type.  It allows storing data captured at regularly sampled intervals in a pretty concise format in a single Observation.